# redistribution OSPF RIP of directly connected networks

Tags: routing, ospf, rip

I am trying to learn redistribution between RIP and OSPF. 
I am using packet tracer.
I have one router BRANCH that is configured with `RIP v2`. On fa0/0 there is the network `172.16.56.0/25`, on fa0/1 the network `172.16.54.0/23`.
BRANCH is connected via serial link to HM router(network `172.16.56.128/30`). HM router has to take care of the redistribution. ON HM, directly connected through fa0/1 there is a network (`172.16.53.0/25`) which is in the OSPF area, however BRANCH knows about that network through RIP. How can I avoid this? 
I think it might be related to summarization because on HM I have another network(`192.168.8.192/28`) connected to Fa0/0 which is learned via OSPF. I have issued 'no auto-summary' on both routers but still I have this problem. Anyone can help me? Thank you

Here route table of BRANCH

```
     172.16.0.0/16 is variably subnetted, 8 subnets, 5 masks
R       172.16.48.1/32 [120/14] via 172.16.56.129, 00:00:08, Serial0/0/1
R       172.16.52.0/24 [120/14] via 172.16.56.129, 00:00:08, Serial0/0/1
R       172.16.53.0/25 [120/1] via 172.16.56.129, 00:00:08, Serial0/0/1  //PROBLEM
R       172.16.53.128/30 [120/14] via 172.16.56.129, 00:00:08, Serial0/0/1
R       172.16.53.132/30 [120/1] via 172.16.56.129, 00:00:08, Serial0/0/1
C       172.16.54.0/23 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/0
C       172.16.56.0/25 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/1
C       172.16.56.128/30 is directly connected, Serial0/0/1
     192.168.8.0/24 is variably subnetted, 2 subnets, 2 masks
R       192.168.8.0/24 is possibly down, routing via 172.16.56.129, Serial0/0/1
R       192.168.8.192/28 [120/14] via 172.16.56.129, 00:00:08, Serial0/0/1
R*   0.0.0.0/0 [120/14] via 172.16.56.129, 00:00:08, Serial0/0/1
```

The routes with a metric 14 are the ones redistributed.
HM:

```
     172.16.0.0/16 is variably subnetted, 8 subnets, 5 masks
O       172.16.48.1/32 [110/129] via 172.16.53.133, 01:25:54, Serial0/0/0
O       172.16.52.0/24 [110/129] via 172.16.53.133, 01:25:54, Serial0/0/0
C       172.16.53.0/25 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/1
O       172.16.53.128/30 [110/128] via 172.16.53.133, 01:26:04, Serial0/0/0
C       172.16.53.132/30 is directly connected, Serial0/0/0
R       172.16.54.0/23 [120/1] via 172.16.56.130, 00:00:09, Serial0/0/1
R       172.16.56.0/25 [120/1] via 172.16.56.130, 00:00:09, Serial0/0/1
C       172.16.56.128/30 is directly connected, Serial0/0/1
     192.168.8.0/28 is subnetted, 1 subnets
C       192.168.8.192 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/0
O*E2 0.0.0.0/0 [110/1] via 172.16.53.133, 01:25:54, Serial0/0/0
```

[image: topology]
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use **Distribute Lists** to perform this action. On router BRANCH, do these actions:

First, creating access-list

```
access-list 101 permit <Network You permit here> 
access-list 101 deny 172.16.53.0 0.0.0.128
```

Then config Distribute Lists for RIP

```
router rip
distribute-list 101 in Serial0/0/1
```

Comment: looks like I can't issue the command distribute-list..`BRANCH(config)#router rip
BRANCH(config-router)#distribute-list 1 in se0/0/1`
                          ^
`% Invalid input detected at '^' marker It is complaining about 'distribute'`

Comment: Packet Tracer does not support this command. Using GNS3 instead. Forgetting to note you

Comment: I see... Is there any other way to do it on packet tracer? Does normally (in the real world) cisco routers support this command? 
Thanks

Comment: Of course, yes. Cisco router does support it. Redistribution is part of CCNP, you must use GNS3 for CCNP lab. I think it can not do in Packet Tracert. But maybe you can try config redistribution for OSPF with metric lower than RIP.

Comment: DO you think I can change the metric of rip to a higher one? because rip has metric 1, so to go lower I should use 0

Comment: Can you post your topo?

Comment: not really, I need 10 in reputation and I just joined... i have only 8

Comment: OK, just try `router ospf; redistribute rip metric 200 subnets` on router HM

Comment: I think that is changing the metric of rip redistributed into ospf, so that the rip routers in the ospf routing tables wil have a metric of 200 right? However it is not the issue I am trying to solve. My problem is related to the other redistribution, if it makes sense to you... sorry I can't post the topology

Comment: I edited the question, now the topology is up